# How to restrict Google Custom Search to a specific URL?

Tags: search, google-custom-search

On a web page is a very long list of company names.
Each name is a link to a profile page located beneath the list page.

So the list page is located here

```
http://example.com/companies/
```

And profiles are here

```
http://example.com/companies/companyOne  
http://example.com/companies/companyTwo  
http://example.com/companies/companyThree
```

I want to implement a Google Custom Search box on that list page, so that a visitor could enter a query and be presented with only the relevant company names. I have created a separate page for the search results, here:

```
http://example.com/companies/results
```

So I guess basically, I want to **limit the search to that single list page**:

```
http://example.com/companies/
```

I've searched for code and documentation but what I have right now returns results from all the pages of the website. And the **setSearchStartingCallback is never called**.

(Sorry I cannot provide live URLS, this is a private beta.) **Thanks for any ideas**!

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    google.load('search', '1', {language : 'fr', style : google.loader.themes.MINIMALIST});
    google.setOnLoadCallback
    (  
        function() 
        {
            var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('MY_GOOGLE_ID_THINGIE');            
            customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);            
            customSearchControl.setSearchStartingCallback
            (
                this,
                function(control, searcher, query) 
                {
                    alert("setSearchStartingCallback");
                    searcher.setQueryAddition("inurl:www.example.com/companies/");    
                    searcher.setRestriction(google.search.Search.RESTRICT_EXTENDED_ARGS,{"as_sitesearch": "www.example.com/companies/"});                    
                }            
            )                        
            var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
            options.setAutoComplete(true);
            customSearchControl.setAutoCompletionId('MY_GOOGLE_ID_THINGIE+qptype:1');
            options.enableSearchboxOnly("http://www.example.com/companies/results");
            customSearchControl.draw('cse-search-form', options);
        }
        ,true
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Found a solution by reading [this](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/customsearch/implementation/PxIg1RviXok). Basically, because I'm using the 'searchbox only' option, the setSearchStartingCallback stuff should be placed in the code of the RESULTS page. HTH someone someday!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
customSearchOptions[google.search.Search.RESTRICT_EXTENDED_ARGS] =  {'as_sitesearch' : 'mywebsite.com/dir/*'};
```